# Alternate every 3 items and 4 items

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a number of items in an array, say more than 14 items.

How can I group them into 2 different groups in this manner: The first 3 (#1,2,3) will be in array A, next 4 (#4,5,6,7) will be in array B, next 3 (#8,9,10) will be in array A, next 4 (#11,12,13,14) will be in array B and so on.

I tried using modulos, but half way through I realized that numbers with factors of 3 and 4 will not be able to be differentiated by using modulos.

*I'm using Javascript/PHP for this, but any similar language is fine*

Comment: What have you tried?  Also, the answer is entirely language-dependent.  Please pick one.

Comment: Also. What will happen if there are items left/ do not fit into your 3-4-3-4 scheme?

Comment: PHP and Javascript are very similar. Either one is fine. If I have to choose one, Javascript!

Comment: @Hippo they if there are 2 items left and the previous items before them were placed into the group of 3s, then the left over will go into the one with groups of 4.

Comment: Why is this tagged `c`? Tag removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For JavaScript:

```
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];
for (var i=0; i< input.length; i++) {
    if (i % 7 < 3) 
        array1.push(input[i]);
    else
        array2.push(input[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would pair a modulus-7 with a less-than-3 check... something like this (php):

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
  if($i%7 < 3) {
    $sortA[] = $array[$i];
  } else {
    $sortB[] = $array[$i];
  }
}
```

Comment: it's worth noting that as a technique this is possible in any of the languages you tagged, just syntax would be different. Perhaps c being the most different for it's lower level handling of arrays.